# Custom function to wrap word entries in square brackets

Tags: vba, excel, formatting, excel-2010

Please help me write a custom function in EXCEL 2010 (VBA).

Here is what I need:

A1: word
=inSquareBrackets(A1)

The output should be: [word]

I simply need a function that will enclose a cell's value in square brackets.

Comment: Creating an UDF means having macros in the workbook, which means having the message appearing when you open it. In some computers the macros are disabled, and some users don't even see the button and don't click on it, and the UDF doesn't work. For such a simple job I would avoid adding VBA (unless it's already there). I would use the formatting suggested by pnuts or the formula suggested by tigeravatar.

Answer (score 6):

Does this really need a custom function (UDF)?  You could do this quite simply by:

```
="["&A1&"]"
```

[EDIT]:
If it has to be a UDF, this will suffice:

```
Public Function em(ByVal strInput As String) As String
    em = "[" & strInput & "]"
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know that one. I wanted user defined function. I have to type that thing many times a day. Would you agree that this: =em(a1) is shorter than what you wrote? :-)

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated. Looks pretty complicated. That works magic.Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`"["@"]"` as a Custom format will enclose all text in a cell so formatted in square brackets. Something like this  `#,##0.00;#,-##0.00;#,##0.00;"["@"]"` is you don't want numbers formatted that way also.

In order to apply the formatting select the cells you want to format, press `Ctrl+1`, click on Number, on Custom, on Type, and type the text shown above.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you wrote. I should copy that thing and paste it into VBA formula editor?

Comment: Why was my edit rolled back? I thought it would help Alex, which seems not to know how to apply the format suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just write this way

```
=CONCATENATE("[",A1,"]")
```

Comment: Thanks, but I know that one. I wanted user defined function. I have to type that thing many times a day. Would you agree that this: =em(a1) is shorter than what you wrote? :-)